# Cant load 2 php pages with start_session() at the same time

Tags: php, session

I have these two php pages. When I navigate first to *test.php* and then to *test2.php* , *test2.php* will wait to load until *test.php* is done loading. Is there any way I can prevent this? This does not happen when I don't use session_start().

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
sleep(10);
echo "Loaded Page 1";
?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Loaded Page 2";
?>
```

Comment: I tried tne code. It works without any problem. THe only change I did was that I replaced the line with echo "Loaded Page 1"; to echo "Loaded Page 2";

Comment: Yes I forgot to replace the 1 with 2, but that doesn't solve anything for me. I think it has something to do with apache configuration or something..

Comment: `code` works without any problem

Comment: What do you mean with 'works', Can you load test2.php while test.php is still running, or does it wait with loading until test.php is done loading?

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to be like this. In the first example the code wil prevent opening other pages starting `session_start();` as long as the code is running.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';

    sleep(10);
?>
```

This can be fixed by using `session_write_close();` when you don't need to write to the session file and make it available for other pages.

You will still be able to read session data after closing the session.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'foo';
    session_write_close();

    sleep(10);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php